# How to get day name in a date in node js

Tags: javascript, date, time, meanjs

I have a date like this

2017-06-23
and my desired output is

Friday June 23 2017

```
 v.npi.appointment_dates[j] = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
```

But because of the day: 'numeric'  I am missing the day name. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to format a date using JS?

Comment: Have a look at the Date object and construct it on your own...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @evolutionxbox...yes

Comment: Could you use something like moment.js

Comment: It's not because of `day: 'numeric' `, it's because you've omitted `weekday: 'long'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `weekday: 'long'` in the options object:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    }));
```

If you want to adopt the the browser default language, use *undefined*:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    }));
```

Even with *options* support, the result of *toLocaleString* is still implementation dependent as the "locale" option is actually a language code, which may not be what the user expects even if they speak that language and the browser developers may not have chosen the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you're looking for.

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var dayNames = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
  var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

  var dayOfMonth = date.getDate()
  var dayOfWeekIndex = date.getDay()
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth()
  var year = date.getFullYear()

  return dayNames[dayOfWeekIndex] + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' +  dayOfMonth + ' ' + year;
}
```

You should take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which will help you a lot with formatting and tons of other date issues.

Comment: I would add +1 do the dayOfWeekIndex

Comment: You have an error in `dayNames`: the second one should be `TUESDAY`, not `Thursday`